# Edittext : custom error popup

Tags: android, android-edittext

How can i custom the layout of the popup **setError** in edittext

```
editTextPosition.setError(getResources().getString(R.string.txt_err_adresse_site),mDrawable );
```

i Override the setError() method  to custom the icon

```
@Override
public void setError(CharSequence error, Drawable icon) {

    super.setError(error, icon);


}
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MyEditText extends EditText {
    public MyEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public void setError(CharSequence error, Drawable icon) {
       // setCompoundDrawables(null, null, icon, null); 
    }
}
```